# Obtaining variable

Tags: delphi, variables

i obtained an example on how to create a login screen before the main form is created. 
Howwever i do not know how to obtain the variable before the login screen closes. I am trying to pass the variable

```
SelectedUserName : String;
SelectedUserIdNo, SelectedCoyId : Integer;
```

from the loginfrm to the mainform for further processing.

any ideas.

thanks in advance.

here is main code:

```
program Pac;

{$R *.res}

uses
  ExceptionLog, Forms,
  MainForm in 'Main\MainForm.pas' {MainFormFrm} ,
  Datamodule in 'Main\Datamodule.pas' {DataModuleFrm: TDataModule} ,
  Login in 'Security\Login.pas' {LoginFrm};

begin
  if tLoginFrm.Execute then
  begin
    Application.Initialize;
    Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
    Application.CreateForm(TMainFormFrm, MainFormFrm);
    Application.CreateForm(TDataModuleFrm, DataModuleFrm);
    Application.Run;
  end
  else
  begin
    Application.MessageBox
      ('You are not authorized to use the application. The password is "delphi".',
      'Password Protected Delphi application');
  end;
end.
```

My Login code is :

```
unit Login;

interface

uses
  Windows, .. .. ..;

type
  TLoginFrm = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    ButtOk: TButton;
    ButtCancel: TButton;
    cxMaskEditUserId: TcxMaskEdit;
    cxMaskEditPw: TcxMaskEdit;
    ButtReset: TButton;
    Label2: TLabel;
    QueryUser: TMSQuery;
    MSConnectionMain: TMSConnection;
    procedure ButtOkClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CheckMenuAccess;
    procedure ButtResetClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  public
    SelectedUserName: String;
    SelectedUserIdNo, SelectedCoyId: Integer;
    { Public declarations }
    class function Execute: boolean;
  end;

implementation

uses DataModule, MainForm, OutletListing;

{$R *.dfm}

class function TLoginFrm.Execute: boolean;
begin
  with TLoginFrm.Create(nil) do
    try
      Result := ShowModal = mrOk;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;

procedure TLoginFrm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MSConnectionMain.Connected := True;
end;

procedure TLoginFrm.ButtOkClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { Verify users are in list of users }
  With QueryUser Do
  Begin
    Active := False;
    if cxMaskEditUserId.EditValue = Null then
      ParamByName('UserId').Clear
    ELSE
      ParamByName('UserId').AsString := cxMaskEditUserId.EditValue;
    if cxMaskEditUserId.EditValue = Null then
      ParamByName('Userpassword').Clear
    ELSE
      ParamByName('Userpassword').AsString := cxMaskEditPw.EditValue;
    Active := True;
    If (FieldByName('UserId').IsNull) or
      (cxMaskEditUserId.EditValue = Null) Then
    Begin
      cxMaskEditUserId.EditValue := Null;
      cxMaskEditPw.EditValue := Null;
      cxMaskEditUserId.SetFocus;
    End
    Else
    Begin
      OutletListingFrm := TOutletListingFrm.Create(Self);
      SelectedUserIdNo := FieldByName('UserIdNo').AsInteger;
      SelectedUserName := FieldByName('UserName').AsString;
      OutletListingFrm.SelectedUserId := FieldByName('UserIdNo').AsInteger;
      IF OutletListingFrm.ShowModal = mrOk THEN
      BEGIN
        SelectedCoyId := FieldByName('CoyId').AsInteger;
        ModalResult := mrOk;
      END
      ELSE
        ModalResult := mrCancel;
      OutletListingFrm.Free;
    End;

 End;

 end.
```

Answer (score 7):

Create a record containing the information to be returned from the login form:

```
type
  TLoginInfo = record
    SelectedUserName: string;
    SelectedUserIdNo: Integer;
    SelectedCoyId: Integer;
  end;
```

Then return such a record from the `Execute` method of the login class:

```
function Execute(out LoginInfo: TLoginInfo): Boolean;
```

If the login is successful, then the implementation of the `Execute` method needs to fill out these details.

Then pass the information to the main form. You cannot do that in the call to `Application.CreateForm`. So instead you'd need a different method on `TMainFormFrm` that can be called after the main form has been created. And that method would receive the `TLoginInfo` record returned from the successful login.

So to `TMainFormFrm` you would add a public method named `InitialiseWithLoginInfo`, say.

```
procedure InitialiseWithLoginInfo(const LoginInfo: TLoginInfo);
```

Then your .dpr file would look like this:

```
var
  LoginInfo: TLoginInfo;

begin
  if tLoginFrm.Execute(LoginInfo) then
  begin
    Application.Initialize;
    Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
    Application.CreateForm(TMainFormFrm, MainFormFrm);
    MainFormFrm.InitialiseWithLoginInfo(LoginInfo);
    Application.CreateForm(TDataModuleFrm, DataModuleFrm);
    Application.Run;
  end
  else
  begin
    Application.MessageBox
      ('You are not authorized to use the application. The password is "delphi".',
      'Password Protected Delphi application');
  end;
end.
```

Comment: thks david, but tLogininfo is undeclarted indentifier during compile.

Comment: Well, then you need to declare it!

Comment: yeah. i place the type
  TLoginInfo = record
    SelectedUserName: string;
    SelectedUserIdNo: Integer;
    SelectedCoyId: Integer;
  end; at the login form.

Comment: Well, it needs to go in the interface section of a unit that is used by every other unit that uses it. Probably that means in the login unit.

Comment: my dpr has a invalid typecase at tLoginFrm(LoginInfo).Execute.

Comment: That's because that code is invalid and different from the code in my answer. That's a typecast, and an invalid one. But the code in the answer calls a method, passing `LoginInfo` as a parameter. Try to understand answers rather than using them blindly. It's important for you to learn rather than just treat this as a black box. Also, please can you learn about voting and accepting answers.